# DirectX Firefox Plugin rendering artifacts

Tags: directx, firefox-3, npapi

> **QUICK ANSWER**: For those of you who reach this page via Google looking for
>   a solution to the same problem, try
>   this quick fix (suggested by Goz) -
>   Add **D3DCREATE_FPU_PRESERVE** to the
>   behavior flags on your CreateDevice()
>   call. That cleared it up for me!

I'm creating a DirectX 9-based NPAPI plugin. It seems to be working well in Chrome and Opera, but in Firefox I get strange rendering artifacts. Upon initializing DirectX (no rendering needs to be done for the artifact to appear) all or parts of the Firefox UI will turn black. Resizing the window (IE: Initiating a repaint) clears up the artifacts and the plugin seems to work properly at that point, but this is obviously not a desirable "feature". I have found that several others online have mentioned this issue, most claiming that it began with Firefox 3. Only [one post](http://www.nabble.com/Using-Direct3D9-in-FF3-Gecko1.9-plugin-ts19519493.html) mentions any solution being found, but the author doesn't seem to keen on divulging how.

Is anyone familiar with this issue and a possible solution? From the linked post it would seem to be related to the way DX is initialized, but I've yet to find a combination that prevents the issue.

This is the DX Initialization code I'm using (Error Handling removed for clarity):

```
RECT rc;
GetClientRect(pluginHwnd, &rc);

D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS d3d9PresentParams;
ZeroMemory(&d3d9PresentParams, sizeof(D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS));    

d3d9PresentParams.hDeviceWindow = pluginHwnd;
d3d9PresentParams.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;
d3d9PresentParams.Flags = D3DPRESENTFLAG_DEVICECLIP; // Failed attempt to solve FF issue
d3d9PresentParams.EnableAutoDepthStencil = FALSE; // No depth testing
d3d9PresentParams.PresentationInterval = D3DPRESENT_INTERVAL_ONE; // Use Vsync

d3d9PresentParams.MultiSampleType = D3DMULTISAMPLE_NONE; // Don't care about Multisampling
d3d9PresentParams.MultiSampleQuality = 0;

d3d9PresentParams.BackBufferCount = 1; 
d3d9PresentParams.BackBufferWidth = rc.right - rc.left; 
d3d9PresentParams.BackBufferHeight = rc.bottom - rc.top;  
d3d9PresentParams.BackBufferFormat = D3DFMT_UNKNOWN; // Use the same color format as windows 

d3d9PresentParams.Windowed = TRUE; // Explicitly windowed
d3d9PresentParams.FullScreen_RefreshRateInHz = 0;

d3d9->CreateDevice( D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, D3DDEVTYPE_HAL, pluginHwnd, D3DCREATE_HARDWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING, &d3d9PresentParams, &d3d9Device );
```

Comment: Do you want to show us YOUR DX initialisation code?

Comment: Wish granted. I would have done so earlier, but I wanted to clean up and double check a few things. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing I can think of off the top of my head is setting the "D3DCREATE_NOWINDOWCHANGES" behaviour flag on device creation.

**Edit1:**
You could try setting backbufferwidth and height to 0 and let it inherit the info from the window.

Might also be worth trying setting the D3DCREATE_FPU_PRESERVE flag and D3DCREATE_MULTITHREADED.

Comment: Not a bad guess, but this doesn't seem to make any difference. Shame, I was hoping it would! :(

Comment: Shockingly, D3DCREATE_FPU_PRESERVE did it! Wow! That actually indicates a problem in Firefox to me, but at least this provides a workaround. Thank you thank you thank you! I would have never thought to try that on my own!

Comment: It suddenly dawned on me that Firefox might be expecting a certain FPU  prceision and D3D plays around with FPU precision quite bizarrely.

Glad you are sorted :)

Comment: I used to have exactly the same problem with black UI elements in Firefox 3.0. And worse, Firefox 3.5 crashes with a plugin that doesn't use D3DCREATE_FPU_PRESERVE (see https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=499682). Using D3DCREATE_FPU_PRESERVE fixed both.