# Direct3D app screws up XULRunner

Tags: xul, direct3d, xulrunner

I have an app using a render engine which can switch between D3D and OpenGL (on Windows at least!) We also use XULRunner for embedded web-browser functionality. XULRunner also appears to use D3D and when our engine is in D3D mode, XUL stops working - it just renders black the whole time.

"Use OpenGL" isn't the answer I'm looking for, so what can I do? We are using D3D9.

**edit:** Apparently GL support is immature, on non-Windows platforms no hardware acceleration is used by default. We've tried to disable it but either there is another bug, or we're not using the right flags. I can't find a good reference for them.

**edit:** Current release versions of XULRunner as used in FF 3.x *don't* support hardware acceleration. And yet still, the moment a D3D9 device is created, the Gecko render engine starts painting solid black.

Answer (score 0):

An old question, but both these threads have answers:

- [DirectX Firefox Plugin rendering artifacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310034/directx-firefox-plugin-rendering-artifacts)
- [Writing a plugin using NPAPI + D3D. It works on Firefox, but the browser blacks out. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101927/writing-a-plugin-using-npapi-d3d-it-works-on-firefox-but-the-browser-blacks)